# Use checkboxes to set non-contiguous print area

Tags: excel, vba

'With the help of a friend (mostly him) we wrote a bit of code to add any of 5 printable areas to the print area for a worksheet based on 5 corresponding checkboxes. A click box exucutes the add to print area, and a different and far simpler command line clears it. The following works pefectly fine, so I wanted to share it, and if anyone has a different or more concise way of going about it we'd be curious to see it.  He rarely programs in VBA so he had to brute-force his way through it. Anyway, here it is:

```
Private Sub Message_Click()

Dim Ranges() As Range
Dim rangeCount As Integer
rangeCount = 0

If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("PrintArea1").Object.Value Then
    rangeCount = rangeCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Ranges(rangeCount)
    Set Ranges(rangeCount) = Range("Sect1PULC", Range("Sect1PLLC").Offset(0, 1))
End If
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("PrintArea2").Object.Value Then
    rangeCount = rangeCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Ranges(rangeCount)
    Set Ranges(rangeCount) = Range(Range("Sect2PULC"), Range("Sect2PLLC").Offset(0, 1))
End If
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("PrintArea3").Object.Value Then
    rangeCount = rangeCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Ranges(rangeCount)
    Set Ranges(rangeCount) = Range(Range("Sect3PULC"), Range("Sect3PLLC").Offset(0, 1))
End If
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("PrintArea4").Object.Value Then
    rangeCount = rangeCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Ranges(rangeCount)
    Set Ranges(rangeCount) = Range(Range("Sect4PULC"), Range("Sect4PLLC").Offset(0, 1))
End If
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("PrintArea5").Object.Value Then
    rangeCount = rangeCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Ranges(rangeCount)
    Set Ranges(rangeCount) = Range(Range("Sect5aPULC"), Range("Sect5aPLLC").Offset(0, 1))

    rangeCount = rangeCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Ranges(rangeCount)
    Set Ranges(rangeCount) = Range(Range("Sect5bPULC"), Range("Sect5bPLLC").Offset(0, 1))
End If


Dim PrintSection As Range
If rangeCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
If rangeCount = 1 Then Set PrintSection = Ranges(1)
If rangeCount = 2 Then Set PrintSection = Application.Union(Ranges(1), Ranges(2))
If rangeCount = 3 Then Set PrintSection = Application.Union(Ranges(1), Ranges(2), Ranges(3))
If rangeCount = 4 Then Set PrintSection = Application.Union(Ranges(1), Ranges(2), Ranges(3), Ranges(4))
If rangeCount = 5 Then Set PrintSection = Application.Union(Ranges(1), Ranges(2), Ranges(3), Ranges(4), Ranges(5))
If rangeCount = 6 Then Set PrintSection = Application.Union(Ranges(1), Ranges(2), Ranges(3), Ranges(4), Ranges(5), Ranges(6))

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
 .PrintArea = PrintSection.Address
 .Orientation = xlPortrait
 .Zoom = False
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
 .FitToPagesTall = False
 .CenterHorizontally = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would skip the counter and the range array. Just define one range and add to it. Something like:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet, rngPrint As Range
Set wks = ActiveSheet

If wks.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True Then
    If rngPrint Is Nothing Then
        Set rngPrint = wks.Range("I4:L9")
    Else
        Set rngPrint = Union(rngPrint, wks.Range("I4:L9"))
    End If
End If

If wks.OLEObjects("CheckBox2").Object.Value = True Then
    If rngPrint Is Nothing Then
        Set rngPrint = wks.Range("I12:L17")
    Else
        Set rngPrint = Union(rngPrint, wks.Range("I12:L17"))
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simplify it and shorten it *a lot* by exploiting the naming conventions you made on your checkboxes and named ranges.

```
Private Sub Message_Click()
  Dim prtArea As String, i As Long
  For i = 1 To 5
    If Sheet2.OLEObjects("PrintArea" & i).Object.Value Then
        If Len(prtArea) > 0 Then prtArea = prtArea & ","
        prtArea = prtArea & Range("Sect" & i & "PULC").Address & ":" & _
          Range("Sect" & i & "PLLC").Offset(0, 1).Address
    End If
  Next

  With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
   .PrintArea = prtArea
   .Orientation = xlPortrait: .Zoom = False: .FitToPagesWide = 1
   .FitToPagesTall = False: .CenterHorizontally = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Also notice that this gives you more control than what you had, because you can select the sections arbitrarily, while for example, your code had to include `section 1` if you wanted to only print `section 2`.